# Removing single dot path names in URL in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, url, char

I'm making a function in an apache module which is supposed to fix URLs that are thrown at it. Currently I'm trying to remove single dot path names.

For example, if my URL is:

```
http://example.com/1/./2/./3/./4.php
```

Then I want the URL to be:

```
http://example.com/1/2/3/4.php
```

However I'm stuck with the logic. I'm using pointers in an effort to make this function run as fast as possible. I'm confused at the logic I should apply at the lines with `//?` added to the end of them.

Can someone give me advice on how to proceed? Even if its some hidden manual online? I searched bing and google for answers with no success.

```
static long fixurl(char *u){
  char u1[10000];
  char *u11=u1,*uu1=u;
  long ct=0,fx=0;
  while (*uu1){
    *u11=*uu1;
    if (*uu1=='/'){
      ct++;
      if (ct >=2){
        uu1++;
        break;
      }
    } else {
      ct=0;
    }
  }

  while (*uu1){ 
    if (*uu1!='/') { //?
      if (*uu1!='.') {
        *u11=*uu1;
         u11++;
      } //?
    } //?
    uu1++;
  }

  *u11='\0';
  strcpy(u,u1);
  return fx;
}
```

Comment: If you are asking for help (and even for your own sake) it might be a good idea to put in a few comments and use more meaningful variable names.

Comment: Do you seriously call your variables `u`, `u1`, `u11`, `uu1`, `ct`, `fx`? These names are not only meaningless, they are even terribly confusing!

Comment: I was trying to make them as short as possible

Comment: @Mike Maybe try to make them as meaningful as possible in future. Having them shorter or longer doesn't change the efficiency of the program in any meaningful way and makes it much harder for people (including you) to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forget to look ahead one character here:

```
if (*uu1!='/') { //?
  if (*uu1!='.') {
```

– you are checking the same character twice (against a 'not', so it could have some use, but your question marks indicate you are not sure what to do there and further on).

Note that you actually need to look ahead *two* characters. If you encounter a slash, test the next character for a `.` *and* the one after that for another `/`.

Rather than trying to fix your code (what is `fx`, the returned value, supposed to be?), I'd rewrite it from scratch to copy from `source` to `dest` and skip the offending sections. The `continue` makes sure that a sequence `/1/././2` gets cleansed correctly to just `/1/2` – it needs a chance to check the second slash again, so I just throw it back into the loop.

```
void fixurl (char *theUrl)
{
    char *source, *dest;

    source = dest = theUrl;
    while (*source)
    {
        if (source[0] == '/' && source[1] == '.' && source[2] == '/')
        {
            source += 2;  /* effectively, 'try again on the next slash' */
        } else
        {
            *dest = *source;
            source++;
            dest++;
        }
    }
    *dest = 0;
}
```

(Afterthought:)

Interestingly, adding proper support for removal of `/../` is fairly trivial. If you test for that sequence, you should search backwards for the last `/` before it and reset `dest` to that position. You'll want to make sure the path is still valid, though.

Comment: I need to learn the continue statement more. At least your code works.

Comment: I like your answer but if I may suggest getting rid of `continue`

Comment: @GRC: I inserted the `continue` only after trying a double period/slash combo (which does not appear in OP's example). Actually  I don't see how removing it would make the code more efficient. As it is, this routine can handle an unlimited sequence of `/./`! (Oh I suppose it could be replaced with `else`. The net effect will be exactly the same.)

Comment: Also, would searching backwards work fine with 64-bit systems? Some 32-bit code doesn't work with 64-bit systems

Comment: Uh. Why would this *not* work? It's totally independent of pointer size. If you want to try the backwards searching for my `/../` then you'll have to check not to pass before the start of the string, or, since you won't want to create malformed paths, the `http://` prefix.

Comment: @Jongware I believe it would and you do not have to replace it with else if, you can do `source[0] == '/' && ((source[1] == '.' && source[2] == '/') || (source[1] == '.' && source[2] == '.' && source[3] == '/'))` it is long but you do not have extra loops to go through

Comment: @GRC: endless lists of tests? Nah. Since the `continue` seems to be new for OP I removed it. The general idea is still the same: only one check per slash for the next characters *and* if period/slash is found, *that* slash needs to be checked again.

Answer (score 1):

This code is untested. In short, it is iterating the string (until the next character is the end sign, since if there is no next character, then you can no longer have a problem) and searches for '/'. When it finds one, analyzes the next character and handles it.

```
static long fixurl(char *u){
    char u1[10000];
    int currentIndex = 0;
    if (*u == '\0') {
        return 0;
    }
    for (; *(u + 1) != '\0'; u++){
        if (*u == '/') {
            if (*(u + 1) == '/') {
                continue;
            } else if ((*(u + 1) == '.') && (*(u + 2) == '.')) {
                u++;
                continue;
            }
        }
        u1[currentIndex] = *u;
    }
    strcpy(u,u1);
    return currentIndex; 
}
```

Comment: a `for()` statement has 3 parameters, separated by 2 semicolons.  this statement: `for (*(u + 1) != '\0'; u++){` raises a compiler warning about 'useless' statement.  suggest: `for ( ; *(u + 1); u++){`

Answer (score 1):

here is a version of the code that works

Note it will remove all '.' that follow a '/'

However, it does not check for extraneous '/' characters being inserted into the output as the OPs posted code does not make that check.

Notice the proper formatting of the `for()` statement

Notice the use of meaningful names, removal of code clutter,
inclusion of a few key comments, etc

Notice the literal characters are placed on the left side of a comparison so writing a '=' when it should be '==' is caught by the compiler.

```
#include <string.h>

long fixurl( char * );

long fixurl(char *rawURL)
{
    char cookedURL[10000] = {'\0'}; // assure new string is terminated
    int currentIndex = 0;

    cookedURL[currentIndex] = rawURL[0];
    rawURL++;

    for ( ; *rawURL; rawURL++)
    {
        // if prior saved char was / and current char is .
        // then skip current char
        if( ( '/' != cookedURL[currentIndex] )
            ||
            ( '.' !=  *rawURL ))
        {
            // copy input char to out buffer
            currentIndex++;
            cookedURL[currentIndex] = *rawURL;
        }
    } // end for

    // copy modified URL back to caller's buffer
    strcpy(rawURL, cookedURL);
    return currentIndex+1;  // number of characters in modified buffer
} // end function: fixurl
```

Comment: this answers' logic has a few edge cases that need to be checked/corrected, such as if a directory name starts with a '.' followed by some other characters.